# How to update $_SESSION variable using update quantity input box

Tags: php, session, post

I used [this](http://jameshamilton.eu/old/shop/products.php) example to create an add to cart page using PHP. The php codes of the 2 pages are here:

http://jameshamilton.eu/sites/default/files/products.php_.txt

http://jameshamilton.eu/sites/default/files/cart.php_.txt

On the cart page, I created a quantity input box and an update link that tries to update the quantities per item. The author of the example [said](http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial#comment-28) what needs to be done, in order to update the quantities. However, I am having trouble doing this.

I'm not sure how to update the quantities stored in the $_SESSION['cart'] with what the user enters in the quantity box, in the cart page. I assume some code must exist in the switch statement for the case: update, in order for an update link to call the action: update, to update quantities per item.

Could someone show me what code to use, in order to update the $_SESSION['cart'], using [this](http://jameshamilton.eu/sites/default/files/cart.php_.txt) example? I tried contacting the author of the example, but he never responded.

UPDATE: Here is the relevant part of the codes I'm using:

https://soc.uwl.ac.uk/~21099475/code.txt

Comment: The example you posted works fine.
Show us YOUR code to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

since there might be more than one products to be updated you need a form to do this.
This is an example to understand what you have to do.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>?action=update" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="quantity[2]" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="quantity[3]" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="quantity[4]" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Once the form has been submitted you have to check the quantities that have been posted and increase or decrease them.

```
if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) {
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $productID => $quantity) {
            if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'][$productID])) {
                $quantity = intval($quantity);
                if($quantity > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$productID] = $quantity;
                }
                else {
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think this example will keep you going.

Comment: Thanks for the code. When I try and update the quantity for an item, an error message appears for the foreach loop. Try adding to cart here: http://21099475.site90.com/buyNow.php

then update the quantity using the update button, then the error will appear.

The updated php code is here https://soc.uwl.ac.uk/~21099475/code.txt

Comment: Check again my example (the html). You should change the input's name attribute to array.
e.g quantity[2] where 2 is the id of the product.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that this is an indicative example just to have you started. You should add extra security (check users input, check if product actually exists etc)

Answer (score -1):

you can't update session but you can used following logic.

firstly you unset your session

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']['product_id']); //don't unset session,unset only quantity session
```

now create a session

```
$_SESSION['cart']['product_id'] = 4; //updated value
```

Comment: What are you talking about? of course you can update a session value. you don't need to unset it. If you're going to post an answer please at least know what you're talking about. Thanks